# Are class methods in C++ instantiated?

Tags: methods, instantiation

I wanted to make some methods static because I didn't want thousands of copies of them, but when I did the sizeof() on my instantiated objects the extra methods in the class didn't seem to make a difference in size, only the variables did.  So are the non-static methods instantiated each time?  If not, why would you use static?  Because I thought that static things don't get instantiated but non-static do.

Comment: Probably only a pointer to the method. If you have 10 methods in your class, then method pointers would take 80 bytes.

Comment: I was just thinking, when you do a sizeof() your class, member variables will always take up bytes but methods never do.  Then I realised if you instantiate 100 objects of a class, they each need to have their own set of member variables, because they change, but the instructions of the functions never change no matter which object.  If there is a pointer to each function in each object it definitely doesn't show in sizeof().